# How do I access data defined in a layout's front matter?

Tags: jekyll

I'd like to add some data to a layout file, to be used in my site's nav. I have a writings collection with many articles, and they use a writing layout:

```
// _layouts/writing.html

---
layout: default
site-section: writings
---

<div id="{{ page.site-section }}">
  <article>
    {{ content }}
  </article>

  {% include comments.html %} 
</div>
```

I tried access the `site-section` variable via `page.site-section`, but it's not working.

How can I access that data?

Answer (score 0):

It works here.

Try to do a `{{ page }}` it is supposed to show all the variables.